# Amazon S3 Permissions by Client code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been converting an existing application to an EC2, S3 and RDS model within AWS, so far it's going well but I've got a problem I can't seem to find any info on.

My Web application accesses the S3 box for images and documents, the way this is stored is by client code,

```
Data/ClientCode1/Images  
Data/ClientCode2/Images  
Data/ClientABC/Images -- etc
```

The EC2 hosting the web application also works within a similar structure, so `www.programname.com/ClientCode1/Index.aspx` as an example, this has working security to prevent cross client access.

Now when `www.programname.com/ClientCode1/Index.aspx` goes to access the S3 for images, I need to make sure it can only access the `ClientCode1` folder on the S3, the goal is to prevent client A seeing the images/documents of client B if you had a tech sort trying.

Is there perhaps a way to get the page referrer, or is there a better approach to this issue?

Comment: In Amazon the access control is done using IAM policies. Documentation starts here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use the URL or referrer to control access to Amazon S3, because that information is presented to your application (not S3).

If all your users are accessing the data in Amazon S3 via the same application, it will be **the job of your application** to enforce any desired security. This is because the application will be using a single set of credentials to access AWS services, so those credentials will need access to all data that the application might request.

**To clarify:** Amazon S3 has no idea which page a user is viewing. Only your application knows this. Therefore, your application will need to enforce the security.

Comment: What you say is "true" with a fuzzy, non-boolean sort of truth... S3 *does* generally know what page the browser *reports* that you are viewing and there's limited support for this in IAM policies with the `aws:Referer` [condition key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition)... yet the answer is still correct, because this capability is not relevant.  This is trivial to defeat/bypass, since the referer source is the browser itself, and thus never trustworhy, so this is not suitable for use as a security mechanism.  The app needs to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, seems to work well

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "http referer policy example",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::clientdata/Clients/Client1/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/Client1/*","http://example.com/Client1/*"]}
       }
     },
      {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::clientdata/Clients/Client1/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/Client1/*","http://example.com/Client1/*"]}
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

This allows you to check the referer to see if the URL is from a given path, in my case I have each client sitting in their own path, the bucket follows the same rule, in the above example only a user coming from Client1 can access the bucket data for Client1, if I log in to Client2 and try force an image to the Client1 bucket I'll get access denied.